# Is it possible to import a single field from a json file?

Tags: webpack

I use a json file as a config file.

**myjson.json** file

```
{
  "part1": {
    "param1": 12,
    "param2": "aaa"
  },
  "part2": {
    "param1": 47,
    "param2": "bbb"
  }
}
```

In a js file, I would like to import only one field in a variable. Let's say `part1.param1`. I know that it is not possible to do it in pure js, but does it exist a webpack module to do something like that `import {part1.param1 as val} from './myjson.json'`.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: I was searching for this as well. Any info?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (import {part1.param1 as val} from './myjson.json') and I got error.
but,you can use destructuring easily:

test.json file:

```
{
"part1": {
  "param1": 12,
  "param2": "aaa"
},
"part2": {
  "param1": 47,
  "param2": "bbb"
}
  }
```

I destructured it as below:

```
import Test from "./test.json"
//...
const {part1:{param1}} = Test;
console.log(param1);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am looking for a direct method to get only one value. I know how I could do that with destructuration.